# I am using operator | and & but not getting proper answer

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, operator-keyword

```
public class num {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int i = 5, j = 9, k = 3;
        int w, x;
        w = i | j | k;
        x = i &j & k;
        System.out.println(w);
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

Why are the values `w = 15` and `x = 1`?

Comment: What answer were you expecting?

Answer (score 7):

`&` and `|` are [bitwise operators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation) (AND and OR respectively).

```
5 ->  101
3 ->   11
9 -> 1001
     ----
AND  0001 = 1
OR   1111 = 15
```